# PHP Cron scheduled jobs not executed

Tags: php, cron

I am stuck on configuring corn.

I have the config below in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/home/czhu/mycommand.log 2>&1
```

The scheduled job never gets executed.

I did use `sudo systemctl start crond.service` to start the cron services. Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get any mail messages about the job? Cron likes to send you mail. log into a terminal as the user where you set up the crontab and run `mail`. Also, if you run `ps -ef | grep -i cron` do you see an instance of cron running?

Comment: * * * * * -> need to provide some time slot there to execute it. like 5 * * *  or something

Comment: @Anant Singh---Alive to Die
* * * * * should be fine to run it every 1 minute which is recommended by Moodle: https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if crond is running or not with:

```
systemctl status crond.service
```

If it is not running, maybe you have to enable it to be able to start it

```
sudo systemctl enable crond.service
```

As mentioned in Moodle docs https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Cron, be sure

> your command-line PHP version is compatible with your chosen version of Moodle. The command-line PHP program is different to the one running your web site and is not always the same version